# RxJava/Android: Combine result of two dependent Observables

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have two `Observables`.

1. `Observable<A> getAObservable()` Returns Observable of `A`
2. `Observable<B> getBObservable(A)` Returns Observable of 'B'.

Here `Observable<A>` should execute before `Observable<B>` so that it can pass its result `A` to `getBObservable()` method. Now once `Observable<B>` completes I need to combine the result of these `observable` and `Observable<AB>` should returns.

Options Tried:

1. Take `Observable<A>` and apply flatMap on it so that it transform
   result in `B`. Now at this point I am not having access to `A` data.
   Hence I can't return Observable

   2. I can use `zip` so that once I get the result of both `Observable<A>` and `Observable<B>`, I can combine their result to
      `AB`. But here I cannot set dependency that `Observable<A>` should
      execute before `Observable<B>` and I can't pass the result of
      `Observable<A>` to `Observable<B>`

Codebase:

```
public class Data {

    A a = new A();
    public Observable<AB> getABContext() {
        A a = new A();

        return getAObservable()
                .flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<AB>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<AB> call(final A a) {
                        return getBObservable(a)
                                .flatMap(new Func1<B, Observable<AB>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Observable<AB> call(B b) {
                                        return Observable.just(new AB(a, b));
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
    }

    private Observable<A> getAObservable() {
        return Observable.just(a);
    }

    private Observable<B> getBObservable(A a) {
        return Observable.just(new B(a));
    }

    private static class A {

    }

    private static class B {
        B (A a) {

        }
    }

    private static class AB {
        AB (A a, B b) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: flatMap should be the proper way. Show your usage of the flatMap please. You just have to return Observable<AB> instead of Observable<B> from it.

Comment: @Michal: Thanks for replying I did this using flatMap. But code is not looking good. Is there be any other option than using flatMap. Please reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`flatMap` documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html). It has overloaded method, that apply zip function:

```
    Observable<Pair<A, B>> abObservable = getAObservable()
      .flatMap(
        new Func1<A, Observable<? extends B>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends B> call(A a) {
                return getBObservable(a);
            }
        },
        new Func2<A, B, Pair<A, B>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<A, B> call(A a1, B b1) {
                return new Pair<>(a1, b1);
            }
        }
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying it out at my end. I am not familiar with lambda expression, can you please post it without using lambda expression. It would be great. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating answer.  It return Observable<Pair<A, B>> but I want Observable<AB>. Sorry for disturbing you again, I am not much familiar with RxJava but I want to learn. Please help.

Comment: @SagarTrehan just replace Pair<A,B> with your class, it's very simple :)