# Chaining N dependant observables

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm quite new to reactive programming and I've introduced myself to RxJava2 in Android. For the time being, I've faced easy problems, such as zipping observables. But now, something new cropped up, I'm trying to explain.

Suppose I've got a list of requests `Observable<List<Request>>`. What I want to do is to call a web service which returns per each request, the list of routes (wrapped in an Observable). I've checked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639458/rxjava-android-combine-result-of-two-dependent-observables), but in this case I think I can't flatMap an observable and a list of observables.

How can I do it? Is there any other operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the `Observable<List<Request>>` into `Observable<Request>` using [`flatMapIterable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapIterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). Assuming you have a helper method with the signature `Observable<List<Route>> getListOfRoutes(Request request) { ... }` you can do this:

```java
Observable<List<Request>> obs = ...;
obs.flatMapIterable(l -> l)
   .flatMap(request -> getListOfRoutes(request)
       .doOnNext(routes -> request.setRoutes(routes))
       .map(ign -> request)
   )
   ...
```

This is assuming that you ultimately want `Observable<Request>` to be emitted downstream. If you want a different type, you can do something different in the `map` operator to suit your needs.

Comment: What about then? I want to merge both observables, so that the list of routes is setted to the request.

Comment: @russellhoff You mean you want to call something like `Request.setRoutes(routes)`? What type do you ultimately want to emitted here? `Observable<Request>`? Something else?

Comment: @russellhoff I updated my answer. Let me know if that isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm trying it now. The issue is that routes of each request are fetched using another web service.

Comment: @russellhoff Hmm, why is that an issue?

Comment: Nope, it was @dano

Comment: Perfect!!! Finally I switched to concatMap. Afterwards I wanted to collect every request observable into a list observable of requests with `toList`.