# make parallel API calls using RX Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I have two different endpoints I am using to fetch data for a user. I am using retrofit with the RX Adapter factory. If I make a call to both the endpoints inside a single method sequentially is it considered to be a parallel call executing on two different threads. If not how could I make these API calls parallel using RX? or a way to get the response at the same time while fetching the data in parallel. for example, the first endpoint could take 5 seconds while the second takes 7 seconds but the end response would be available after 7 seconds.

```
fun fetchData() {
    api.getData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            { profileResponse ->
                //ProfileResponse Object
                Timber.d("profileResponse: $profileResponse")
                //store response for later use
                Cache.save("key", profileResponse.toString())
            },
            {
                Timber.e("error")
            }
        )


    api2.getData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            { profileDetails ->
                //profileDetails Object
                Timber.d("profileDetails: $profileDetails")
            },
            {
                Timber.e("error")
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: as far as i know (don't take this as an answer) but in my opinion i believe what you're doing will execute them in parallel. as far as my understanding goes, Schedulers.IO is a threadpool which will grow as it needs to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `subscribeOn()` for each observable so it's already executing in parallel.

> Is there a way to get the response at the same time while fetching the data in parallel. for example, the first endpoint could take 5 seconds while the second takes 7 seconds but the end response would be available after 7 seconds.

For this, you can use `Observable.zip` like the following where the time required is the
maximum of two calls:

```
val disposable = Observable.zip(
        firstNetworkCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        secondNetworkCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        BiFunction{
            firstResonse: ResponseOneType,
            secondResponse: ResponseTwoType ->
            combineResult(firstResponse, secondResponse) }))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { it -> doSomethingWithIndividualResponse(it) }
```

This [article](https://proandroiddev.com/rxjava-2-parallel-multiple-network-call-made-easy-1e1f14163eef) may help to visualize how it's working underneath.

Comment: What does combineresult do here! The return types of responses 1 and 2 are different. How can I combine them?

Comment: @luckysing_noobster just use ```Pair<Response1, Response2>``` where ```Response1``` & ```Response2``` are your two return types. If you want to combine two dependent Observables, this answer should provide u with the code - hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639773/11040422

Answer (score 2):

> If I make a call to both the endpoints inside a single method sequentially is it considered to be a parallel call executing on two different threads. If not how could I make these API calls parallel using RX?

They are parallel. You're subscribing to a an observable on an IO scheduler and not blocking waiting for responses.

> or a way to get the response at the same time while fetching the data in parallel. for example, the first endpoint could take 5 seconds while the second takes 7 seconds but the end response would be available after 7 seconds.

One way is to use [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) to combine your observables to a single observable that emits when all the sources have emitted.

Comment: How do I combine the responses which are emitted? The return types of responses 1 and 2 are different. How can I combine them?

Comment: `Pair<Response1, Response2>`